# UISplitViewController shows detail view first

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am very new to iOS development.  In my app I have a tab bar and in one of the tabs I have a UISplitViewController.  My issue is that when I go to the tab it shows the Detail view first.  Then I have to click the back button to get the the master view.  I have found one other person having this issue on stackoverflow, but the solution was in Objective-c and I am using the storyboard (not sure how to attach a class to it) and swift, so that did not help.

It also does not work when using an ipad in portrait mode.  When I shift to landscape it works fine, but just shows a black screen (no back button) in portrait mode.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

I am not sure what other info you need or what you want me to show, so let me know if I left something out.

adjusted appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let splitViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers![3] as! UISplitViewController

    ///////////////////Always visible property
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible
    ///////////////////
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

Update: ended up fixing following this answer [Open UISplitViewController to Master View rather than Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506713/open-uisplitviewcontroller-to-master-view-rather-than-detail)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample SplitViewController in the project and set the property in the appdelegate. This works for me https://github.com/harsh62/stackoverflow_TestMasterDetailApp

`splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible`

The full function is as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    ///////////////////Always visible property
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible
    ///////////////////
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

References:
[UISplitViewController - set always visible master controller when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167006/uisplitviewcontroller-set-always-visible-master-controller-when)

Comment: thank you. I will try this when I get home and let you know.

Comment: I tried the code and got this error

    Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1024988b0) to 'UISplitViewController' (0x1024a5240).
(lldb)

Comment: You are setting this property, thats why you are getting this error. Try to set `preferredDisplayMode` on the split controller object.

Comment: I created the splitviewcontroller directly in the storyboard, so I don't have a controller class.  Where would I change the preferredDisplayMode?

Comment: Did you check the github example I made for you?

Comment: Yes, I did look at the github example.  I realized that the reason your code was crashing at first is that my rootview was not a navigation controller but a tabbarcontroller.  So I adjusted the code.  But now I am getting an error that it cannot cast my detailController to a UINavigationController